# Android, Initial Program Load, Standby Message

Tags: android, message

My application copies a bunch of files from res.raw to files on the SD Card. This can take tens of seconds. During this time the user is left with a black screen. Some users think that the application has failed. I would like to display a "standby" message.

I have tried Toast. I have tried setContentView(R.layout.main) with a message in the layout. Neither gives the expected results. The screen remains black during the load process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your running this heavy thing in the UI Thread, which will block the interaction with the user. You will have to do this heavy load in another thread. I recommend the Asynctask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

1. onPreExecute(): show the standby message.
2. doInBackground(Params...): do the heavy load.
3. onPostExceute(Result r): you're done with the heavy load, so go ahead and remove the standby message.

Comment: Another option is to show non-cancelable progress dialog with standby message which prevent user from any actions during copy.